# Unable to enter keyboard input into android avd java app when naming new device. (Mavericks, Homebrew)

Tags: android, homebrew, osx-mavericks

I'm on Mavericks, and have installed the android-sdk via Homebrew.

When I Launch the android avd from the commandline

`$android avd`

It displays the list of avds, and when i click 'Create' I am given a form in which to enter the device's information:
[image: No input]

However when I try to type in a device name, the output is sent to my terminal from where I launched the android avd command.

Not sure why the input isn't getting directed into the AVD Name textbox. Mac even shows its the active application running as the os toolbar at the top shows its name.

Comment: Why can't you just create an AVD from Android Studio?

Comment: And can't reproduce on El Capitan

Comment: @cricket_007 was following this tutorial https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

Comment: Genymotion is installable from homebrew too. (via Cask). Like I said, though, I can't reproduce the issue. That link also says you can use Android Studio to write react code

Comment: @cricket_007 hmm, I decided to just try and reinstall a lower version of java then run a fresh install of the android-sdk , seemed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after a bit of mucking around I figured maybe it was the java version of the avd app so :

1. Uninstalled java jdk1.8 and installed jdk1.7
2. To be sure, got fresh install of android-sdk via android site: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools

textinput into AVD name box seems to work now using the site download instead of the homebrew version.